# How to conditionally join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table - **Sales**

| Id | TypeNr | TypeId | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 4.32 | 120 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 2.38 | 0 |

Desired output:

| Id | TypeNr | TypeId | Price | Quantity | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 4.32 | 120 | Blue Shirt |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 2.38 | 0 | 20% Discount |

If `TypeNr` is 0 then I need to make a join to the **Products** table and pull the name associated with the `TypeId`.

If `TypeNr` is 1 then I need to make a join to the **Discounts** table and pull the discount associated with tye `TypeId`.

--
I have tried several methods with IFs / CASE/ELSE but my knowledge of SQL is very limited hence could not get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to display the tables correctly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an excellent use case for `UNION ALL`.

Try this:

```
SELECT Id,
       TypeNr,
       s.TypeId,    
       Price,
       Quantity,
       p.TypeName as Description
FROM   Sales s
   INNER JOIN
       Products p
         ON s.TypeId = p.TypeId
WHERE  s.TypeNr = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,
       TypeNr,
       s.TypeId,    
       Price,
       Quantity,
       d.Discount as Description
FROM   Sales s
   INNER JOIN
       Discounts d
         ON s.TypeId = d.TypeId
WHERE  s.TypeNr = 1
```

What this does:

`UNION ALL` merges two query result sets (with the same number and type of columns).  The difference between a `UNION` and a `UNION ALL` is that a plain `UNION` will perform an implicit `DISTINCT` on the results, whereas a `UNION ALL` won't.  As a result, `UNION ALL` is much faster to return results.

Since `s.TypeNr` can't be both 0 and 1, the two queries won't return any of the same records, so there's no need for a `DISTINCT`.  Therefore, `UNION ALL` can be used.

(I am making some assumptions about field names and types for the sake of this example: adjust as needed!)

(Also, I chose inner joins for simplicity, but if there's any chance that a product description or discount might be missing, use `LEFT OUTER JOINS`.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Ann. note a small type with two SELECTS in your answer for future comers please.

Comment: @SubliminalHash  Thank you for pointing out the typo!  I have fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot join conditionally. Instead, join both tables and use a CASE to select the desired data.

```sql
SELECT
    s.Id, s.TypeNr, s.TypeId, s.Price, s.Quantity,
    CASE
      WHEN s.TypeNr = 0 THEN p.Name
      WHEN s.TypeNr = 1 THEN d.Discount
    END AS Description
FROM
    Sales s
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON s.ProductId = p.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN Discounts d ON s.DiscountId = d.DiscountId
```

You will have to adapt the JOIN ON clauses, as I don't know how you are joining the tables exactly.

I also assume that `d.Discount` is a text. Otherwise you will have to construct it. Something like this

```sql
CAST(d.Discount AS varchar(8)) + '% Discount'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Subquery:

```
select
    Id,
    TypeNr,
    TypeId,
    Price,
    Quantity,
    case
        when
            TypeNr = 0 
        then
(
            select
                Description 
            from
                Products 
            where
                pTypeId = TypeId) 
            when
                TypeNr = 1 
            then
(
                select
                    Description 
                from
                    Discounts 
                where
                    pTypeId = TypeId) 
    end
    as Description 
                from
                    sales;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the joins conditional by adding additional logic to the `on` clauses. Then pick up the correct value, if any, with `coalesce`:

```
select S.Id, S.TypeNr, S.TypeId, S.Price, S.Quantity,
  Coalesce( P.Name, D.Discount ) as Description
  from Sales as S left outer join
    Products as P on S.TypeNr = 0 and S.TypeId = P.TypeId left outer join
    Discounts as D on S.TypeNr = 1 and S.TypeId = D.TypeId;
```

With the `on` conditions being mutually exclusive you are guaranteed to get at least one `null` result between `P.Name` and `D.Discount` and `coalesce` will pick up the other value. Note that both values could be `null` and, as mentioned by Olivier Jacot-Descombes, you may have some data type cleanup to do with the `Discount`.

Food for thought: How often do you use an *unconditional*, i.e. `cross`, join?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, TypeNr, TypeId, Price, Quantity
CASE
    WHEN TypeNr = 1 THEN SELECT Description FROM Products AS p WHERE p.id = TypeNr
    WHEN TypeNr = 0 THEN SELECT Disc FROM Discounts AS d WHERE d.id = TypeNr
END AS Description;
FROM Sales;
```